# Songs with a war atmosphere

Tags: genre

Which Genre of music does this song belong to:

What contributes to a cold and evil atmosphere, like in the following Score in the WW2 movie - Fury (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRAlWtadQRc).

Comment: I am not just asking for recommendations, I am trying to understand what genre this type of song is, as well as identifier what or the factors that makes this type of song [art of that genre

Comment: I edited my question, to get the focus of the recommendations part of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely an element of Gregorian Chant in there, which some may say sounds creepy on its own.  The majority of it is Atmospheric, although the drums most closely resemble Marching Band or some derivative of Military.

I'd say it's a well-scored fusion of all the above styles, which produced a very effective end result.

Comment: Would you say that there is no specific genre for this? If I'd like to find more music like that?

Comment: I don't really think so.  I mean, you could say "Mars, The Bringer Of War" by Holst was the purveyor of it, and that is strictly classical.  Or you can go with the ELP remake of Mars, which is more Progressive Rock.  Most of it relies heavily on Atmospheric, which is more New Age.  So, if anything I'd most closely associate it with Classical or a derivative.  I mean, [take a listen to this](https://magnatune.com/artists/albums/drsounds-abstract?song=1), imagine some war scenes, a few drum hits here and there and some Gregorian Chants over it.

Comment: Thank Johnny. Really appreciate the time you took to explain, and the recommendations/examples you gave. This will definitely help me! Here you go, have an accepted answer :D

Comment: @JohnnyBones Pardon my nitpicking. Those voices are certainly _not_ Gregorian. The latter is one-voiced, smooth, and melodic. These chants in contrast are sharp and chorded. Inspiration isn't impossible, but I think they are too soundtrack-generic to conclude they were inspired more from Gregorian chant than any other kind of choral music.